# Execute insert statement when the case conditions are satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which has a insert statement.The procedure executes an insert statement when the user provides all the values as 0. If the user provides differnt values then a error statement should be returned.

```
case when @test1=0,@test2=0,@test3=0 then 
{Insert statement} 
Else
Case when @test1=0,@test2=0,@test3=1
{select “All cases should be 0”}
Else
Select “Please provide data”
```

In this case I thought case conditions works fine but after reading documentation and some other links it seems syntactically false to write such a statement.

Anyother possible way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For control flow in T-SQL, use `if`, not `case`.  Something like this:

```
if @test1=0 and @test2=0 and @test3=0 
begin 
    {Insert statement} 
end;
Else if @test1=0 and @test2=0 and @test3=1
begin
    {select “All cases should be 0”}
end
Else
begin
    Select “Please provide date”
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF` and to check each variable with `0` value then `COALESCE` and `NULLIF` are helpful as below:

```
IF (@test1 = 0 AND @test2 = 0 AND @test3 = 0) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tmpTable(val1)
    SELECT val1 FROM <table_name>
END
ELSE IF COALESCE(NULLIF(@test1, 0), NULLIF(@test2, 0), NULLIF(@test3, 0)) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 'All cases should be 0'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Please provide data'
END
```